# Enrich policy - Could not obtain lock because policy execution is already in progress

Tags: elasticsearch

I accidentally created enrich policy with typo

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/grooup-info
```

and then i ran execute on enrich

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/group-info/_execute
```

when i saw typo policy creation, i removed it a created enrich policy without typo and tried to run execute again, but now i am getting this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "es_rejected_execution_exception",
        "reason" : "Could not obtain lock because policy execution for [group-info] is already in progress."
      }
    ],
    "type" : "es_rejected_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "Could not obtain lock because policy execution for [group-info] is already in progress."
  },
  "status" : 429
}
```

Is there any way how to fix this error?
Please let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, it's not possible to execute an enrich policy that does not exist, you would get an error like `Could not locate policy with id [group-info]` when running your second command the first time.

So it's only possible because the `group-info` policy already existed when you executed it the first time. And if that's the case, those policy executions are not cancellable, so you'll need to wait until it's finished, delete it with `DELETE /_enrich/policy/group-info`, recreate it and re-execute it properly.

You can monitor the policy execution with

```
GET _tasks?actions=policy*
```

or

```
GET _enrich/_stats
```

Comment: Well in this case i did not get any error or any other response, i waited more then 2 hours without any result. 
The two suggested API calls did not give anything which could help unfortunately. 
At the end restart of the server helped fix any error with the lock.
But anyway thank you.

Comment: What about `GET _cat/tasks?v`? If you don't see any task named *policy, it means the task has finished running already... You can find a hidden index called `.enrich-group-info` when the task has finished running. Can you see it?